# what things are costly to implement in PHP on a large social networking site?

Tags: java, php, c++, performance, facebook

It is very common to hear that C++ or Java should be used on the "back end" to improve performance. I believe sites like Facebook have C++ based "services" for critical performance.

For example: Is it at any time more cost effective to replace SQL "SELECT * FROM ...." type commands passed via PHP with something else because the database is a huge one to search through?

In general can someone explain by examples what kinds of things one should probably not be using PHP for even at the early stages of a site.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Until you reach a point where you are getting enough hits that PHP becomes a bottle neck don't waste your time.  Most of your performance issues will be IO related (ie. database queries), this can be offset quite easily using something like memcached.

Comment: You are not building a large social networking site.  You might think you are, but you aren't.  It's not going to be large.   Build it using the tools and practices that you know well and are comfortable using.  If you need to make deep architectural changes later because you somehow managed to become popular, then so be it.  But deal with that possibility *later*.  Don't over-architect yourself into a corner.

Comment: granted, large number of people is never an issue at the start...but there are scenarios where a large amount of **data** is needed even for a small number of people....in this case worrying about what's efficient is essential to survival....i know not to over architect I am just curious as to the specific reasons and specific examples of things that people worry about when scale of data is relevant....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not web developer, and I am also not PHP programmer and this question is more discussion so let me try.

On this super big type of sites you need smart and efficient algorithms, not efficient languages. Lot of Google code running their website is written in Python, which have same speed compared whit PHP.

I think that database need to be constructed in way, that it returns as least amount of data as possible, that it require as least as possible number of queries and that returned data need as least as possible processing for displaying. It same goes whit insert.

If you manage to design such page in such way, your page will not be processor exhaustive and will mean that it will not matter which language you will use.

You also do not need booletproof type of database like you would use for running bank (100% transation complition, database locking, ... ) so you can balance reliability whit speed. But for this you need specal database.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly would you replace "SELECT ..." *with?* The bigger the database the *more* you should use SQL on it. If access is slow check that the queries you use are well supported by the indexes.

The rest of your question comes under the heading of subjective and argumentative, but from bitter experience I wouldn't use PHP at all for anything expected to grow beyond a very small initial size.

Comment: you said "I wouldn't use PHP for big project", then what is your suggestion? Please share with us

Comment: @Gens, what good would that be? Of course he would recommend whatever he feels most comfortable with; this has nothing to do with whether it’s the most qualified tool for that. Chances are, there is no single most qualified tool for the job. Use whatever you want. It is (almost) never the tool’s fault if you fail.

Comment: @Gens I would use a statically typed and strongly-typed language. There are several well-known examples. PHP fails both those tests.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like facebook are often progressive with often having many re-writes.
But yes, they do often run on c++ DLL's and the such.
SQL although being string based is quite fast. 
The thing to keep in mind thought is that there are hundreds of SQL processing software.
SQL is a language, not a software.

Comment: SQL is a *language* not a protocol, and it is not 'string based'.

Comment: Im reffering to how you comunicate with it. I realise that it is not stored as raw strings.

Comment: You don't communicate with SQL. You write commands *in* SQL that are executed remotely via a vendor-specific protocol. If that means SQL is string-based, so is every other programming language, and that doesn't stop most of them being fast either. The comment doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree..there are many DLL's running written on C++..or even cron jobs that updates every second in the server...but i think there are several databases that facebook uses ..depending on your location you will be connected to that server..and after a data is updated an automatically back end script or code will run to synchronize those databases...